# Visual Studio crashes on Parallels Desktop 8

Tags: mac, crash, visual-studio, parallels, visual-studio-2012

I have a macbook pro with 16GB Ram, as a frequent visual studio user I installed Parallels Desktop so I can use visual studios on my mac. Whenever I open visual studios its very slow and it eventually crashes every time I try to use it.

Is there any mac users out there who has got visual studios on Parallels desktop? or anyone who can help me with having a smooth experience with visual studio.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio. Later versions of Visual Studio use the GPU to make it look pretty, which explain the poor performance within a virtual machine, how much memory is provided to the VM?  What version of Windows is running within the Virtual Machine?

Comment: @Ramhound its Visual Studion 2013, I've given a memory of 8GB Ram. I am running windows 7.

Comment: Disable the GPU acceleration and any feature that uses the GPU

Comment: @Ramhound how is this done? In the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools -> Options... In the Environment - General options there are a few checkboxes that Control the Visual experience in the studio.

Try different settings  by disabling the **Automatically adjust visual experience based on client performance** to be able to manually set the hardware acceleration option.